# Tree-structure Algorithm

Tags: java, combinations, permutation

I have problems with my program. For example I have 5 fields. The fields have the value `true` or `false`. `False` fields *can* be deleted. So I want to find every possible combination of these fields.

My Idea was: For example I have an XML with these fields

- Field1, true
- Field2, true
- Field3, false
- Field4, false
- Field5, false

The result should be:

```
{Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5}
{Field1, Field2,       , Field4, Field5}
{Field1, Field2,       ,       , Field5}
{Field1, Field2,       ,       ,       }
{Field1, Field2, Field3,       , Field5}
{Field1, Field2, Field3,       ,       }
{Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4,       }
{Field1, Field2,       , Field4,       }
```

8 Combinations.

And my idea was, it could solved with a tree-structure. I will check whether current field is "true" or "false". If "true" then I will move a field forward. If the field is "false" I will duplicate the XML and add once with the current "false" field and once without it in a list.
Like on the picture here for example.
[image: tree]

```
public List<List<Fieldmatrix>> permut(List<Fieldmatrix> matrix, int j) {

    while (felderLaenge != j) {

        if (!matrix.get(j).isTrue()) {
            tmpL = iterateLeft(matrix, j);

            tmpR = iterateRight(matrix, j);


        } else {
            tmpL = iterateRight(matrix, j);

        }
        j++;
        return permut(tmpL, j);
    }
    return sammlung;
}
```

`iterateLeft` means delete, `iterateRight` means do not delete.

I can´t implement the duplicate-Function. So I have only 4 Xmls results:
`{1,2,3,4,5}, {1,2,4,5}, {1,2,3,5}, {1,2,3,4}`

Could someone help me?

---

First of all I am thankful for your first support.

The Fieldmatrix-Class look like:

```
public class Fieldmatrix {

private String feld;
private boolean pflicht;

public Fieldmatrix(String feld, boolean pflicht){
    this.feld = feld;
    this.pflicht = pflicht;
}

public String getFeld() {
    return feld;
}

public void setFeld(String feld) {
    this.feld = feld;
}

public boolean isPflicht() {
    return pflicht;
}

public void setPflicht(boolean pflicht) {
    this.pflicht = pflicht;
}
```

}

How can I change this part "prefixWithField.add(?)"
You handle it with String and this works because the List is also type of String.
But I work with List
.

iterateRight() prints only with the console.
ieterateLeft() deletes the current field and prints with the console.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't implement the duplicate-function"?

Comment: Why don't you simply count up? You start with a configuration that is essentially a bool for every field initialized with true, and then you apply an operator on it that searches for the most right element that is deletable, flips it's value and whenever it flipped from false to true, it continues doing that to the left. As one would count up a binary number, only with 0 and 1 reversed and ignoring non-deletable "digits". That said, your question is somewhat unclear - are you asking about an algorithm how to do find all combinations or how to duplicate an XML?

Comment: Also, I really recommend naming everything in english.

Comment: It would help to show us the implementation of `iterateLeft` and `iterateRight`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problems

There are multiple problems:

- If your current tree node has two childs, you have to descend into both, not just the left one.
- At the very end, you returned `sammlung` (engl. `collection`), but never added any elements (at least not in the presented code).
- The `while` loop combined with the recursion seems somewhat odd. But I cannot say much about this without looking at `iterateLeft` and `iterateRight`.

## Implementation

A quick way to implement the function would be as follows.
For simplicity, the `Fieldmatrix` class was replaced by `String`.

```
public static List<List<String>> combine(List<String> fields) {
    return combine(fields, 0, new ArrayList<>());
}

public static List<List<String>> combine(List<String> fields,
                                         int start, List<String> prefix) {
    List<List<String>> combinations = new ArrayList<>();
    if (start >= fields.size()) {
        combinations.add(prefix);
        return combinations;
    }
    String field = fields.get(start);
    if (field.contains("false")) {
        combinations.addAll(combine(fields, start + 1, prefix));
    }
    List<String> prefixWithField = new ArrayList<>(prefix);
    prefixWithField.add(field);
    combinations.addAll(combine(fields, start + 1, prefixWithField));
    return combinations;
}
```

This implementation is not very efficient. A lot of intermediate results are copied over and over again.

## Example

```
List<String> fields = new ArrayList<>();
fields.add("1:true");
fields.add("2:true");
fields.add("3:false");
fields.add("4:false");
fields.add("5:false");
combine(fields).forEach(c -> System.out.println(c));
```

prints

```
[1:true, 2:true]
[1:true, 2:true, 5:false]
[1:true, 2:true, 4:false]
[1:true, 2:true, 4:false, 5:false]
[1:true, 2:true, 3:false]
[1:true, 2:true, 3:false, 5:false]
[1:true, 2:true, 3:false, 4:false]
[1:true, 2:true, 3:false, 4:false, 5:false]
```